# Add friend class after declaration

Tags: c++, oop, encapsulation

I am trying to write a named pipe server in C++. I have a class called `client_pool` which contains a container of the pipe's instances, and a single public member function `write`, which asynchronously sends data to all connected clients.

Problem is, clients have the tendency to disconnect unexpectedly. When this happens, the call to `WriteFileEx` fails with `ERROR_NO_DATA`. When that happens, i want to go to the `client_pool` class and tell it to close the client handle and remove it from the container. However, since `WriteFileEx` is so fricking hard to use, I created a helper class called  `write_context` in an anonymous namespace.

So the end result is, that I want to call a private method in `client_pool`, which is declared in `clients.h`, from the class `write_context`, which is declared in `clients.cpp`. Something like that (details/error handling omitted):

**clients.h**

```
class client_pool {
    struct implementation;
    std::unique_ptr<implementation> pimpl;
public:
    void write(uint8_t *data, size_t size);
};
```

**clients.cpp**

```
struct client_pool::implementation {
    set<HANDLE> connected;
    // ...
    void disconnect(HANDLE victim)
    {
        CloseHandle(victim);
        connected.erase(victim);
    }
};

namespace { struct write_context {
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    client_pool *owner;
    HANDLE target;
    const uint8_t *buffer;
    size_t total_size;
    size_t written;
    // ...
    void next_chunk()
    {
        if(!WriteFileEx(/* ... */, write_context::completion_routine)) {
            if(GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_DATA) {
                // I want to do something like
                owner->pimpl->disconnect(target);
            }
        }
    }
    static void CALLBACK completion_routine(DWORD errcode, DWORD transferred, LPOVERLAPPED overlapped)
    {
        auto self = reinterpret_cast<write_context*>(overlapped);
        self->written += transferred;
        if(errcode == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
            self->next_chunk();
        } else {
            delete self;
        }
    }
}; }

void client_pool::write(uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    for each handle in pimpl->connected {
        auto context = new write_context(this, handle, data, size);
        context->next_chunk();
    }
}
```

Obviously, the line `owner->pimpl->disconnect(target);` doesn't compile because `pimpl` is private. What can I do / what are my alternatvies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly accessing pimpl->connected and write_context directly in your client_pool::write method is kinda contrary to the point of the pimpl idiom. You could probably make a case otherwise, until you run into a problem just like this.

I would just create an implementation::write method for which you can pass through the arguments and a pointer to client_pool.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use a named namespace instead of a anonymous namespace you could place this line inside the class definition:

```
friend void namespace_name::next_chunk()
```

Or there's placing all that extra stuff in the anonymous namespace as static functions inside the class. Because static methods and structs don't change the ABI, you can hide it from all other instances via a preprocessor trick.

Or there's the brutal and horrifying:

```
#define class struct
#define private public
#define protected public
```

Comment: Not as clean as Gerald's solution, but hackish enough for an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Make `write_context` a friend of `implementation`.  Pass `pimpl` as the `owner` of `write_context`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not the best way to use PIMPL idiom.

PIMPL hides implementation details of it's owner and should be accessed only through its owners interface. So, if you want to call "client_pool::implementation" method than it should be moved to "client_pool" interface and its implementation should delegate work to "client_pool::implementation" class. In other case this looks like design bug.

Comment: The problem is that the disconnect() method would be part of the public interface, although it really isn't. The write() method is the only method the interface needs. disconnect()'s purpose is to get rid of dead pipes - in my opinion, an implementation detail.

Comment: In you architecture "write_context::next_chunk" does all the job on writing and detects that pipe is dead. It seems that it needs only pipe handle and can work separately from "client_pool". You can return corresponding return value or throw exception in this method to signal that pipe is dead and handle such situation in client_pool::write by disconnecting the dead pipe. By this re-factoring you can eliminate unnecessary dependencies between classes: "write_context" class will not need "client_pool" to do his job.

Comment: No, I can't. next_chunk is called asynchronously.